# Understanding the SpriteKit scene coordinates

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, coordinates, skspritenode

I have a simple square (SKSpriteNode), 100x100, initially their coordinates are (0,568)

[image: initial step]

I would like move their coordinate to (0,568), like below:

[image: after move]

I don't understand why in the assistant editor, the x coordinate is 70. It should be 50 no? (100/2)
It's not logical for me.

Comment: The height and the width of the diamond is 100 points. However, diagonally across the shape is larger than the height and width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the square is calculated looking at the center of the shape.

### Why the center?

Because the anchor point of this SKSpriteNode is `(0,5, 0,5)`.

### Answer

So in the second image, where is the center?

As you can see it is distant from the left border of the scene and that distance is `70` points.

Answer (score 0):

It would be 50 if the shape was a untilted square. However, the shape is a square skewed to be a diamond. The height and the width are measuring the sides of the square. However, since you have it skewed as a diamond, it only looks like the left-most side is at x = 0.

If the height and width of the shape is 100 points, diagonally across the shape is 140 points. `140/2 = 70`.